# How do you change text to numbers in App Inventor?

Tags: app-inventor

I am currently doing a project which requires sending a text string (via bluetooth) as a group of numbers. A being 0 B being 1 C being 2 etc. I have tried for many hours and failed so i would be very grateful for a response.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not really clear, but I think I get it:
I think this is what you need:
[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrDHY.png)
[image]

You have to of course expand it for every letter in the alphabet, it just checks if a number is in the string, then replaces all of the numbers with the corresponding letters.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i solved the issue anyway but thanks for the help.